# Inserting a new page after each generated page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm generating a `.pdf` file using the **iText 7** library. And I would like to basically duplicate every page, preferably using a `PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE` EventHandler. Because I would like to have each duplicate page, alternating after each other with a different header/footer.

The following image will illustrate the desired result:
[image: Example of desired result]

I realise that this desired result can probably be achieved by generating a single instance first and then using another reader and writer to duplicate each page and add the header/footer with some kind of stamper.
But because of different requirements I would like to solve this while generating. But it might just not be possible the way I want to solve this.

I've tried a couple of things already but I get some strange behaviours and I can't seem to figure this out by myself. I'll add some of this code, which hopefully also helps explaining the issue further.

This is the example code to generate the document:

```
protected void ManipulatePdf(string dest)
{

    var writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    var doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);

    //Custom EventHandler that adds a page footer 
    pdfDoc.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new CustomEndPageEventHandler(pdfDoc)); 

    //The actual generating of the document
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test " + (i + 1)));
        if (i != 2)
        {
            doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        }
    }
    /* I would like to add that in reality it is not known exactly when page-breaks will occur */

    doc.Close();
}
```

And below is the code I have so far for adding the extra pages. Please note that this code is not correct and gives some strange behaviour. 
There is no code for alternating the header/footer yet, this code was simply supposed to insert duplicates between each page.
I'll also add another image below with the generated result, but this is not what is expected.

```
protected class CustomEndPageEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
    protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
    protected float side = 20;
    protected float x = 300;
    protected float y = 25;
    protected float space = 4.5f;
    protected float descent = 3;

    public CustomEndPageEventHandler(PdfDocument pdf) {
        placeholder =
            new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));

    }
    
    public void HandleEvent(Event currentEvent)
    {
        if(!(currentEvent is PdfDocumentEvent docEvent)) return;
        var pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
        var page = docEvent.GetPage();
        var pageNumber = pdf.GetPageNumber(page);
        var pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdf);
        var canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
            .Add($"{pageNumber}");
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        pdfCanvas.AddXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
        pdfCanvas.Release();


        //Here starts the custom code to insert a duplicate
        if ((pageNumber % 2) != 0 && pageNumber < 6)
        {
            pdf.AddPage(pageNumber + 1, page);
            pdf.AddNewPage(pageNumber+2);
        }          

    }

    public void WriteTotal(PdfDocument pdf) {
        var canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
        canvas.ShowTextAligned($"/{pdf.GetNumberOfPages()}",0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    }
}
```

The above code results into [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ1lb.png). I've tried a couple of different variations of this, when you for example when you remove the line `pdf.AddNewPage(pageNumber+2);` then the page with `Test 2` and  `Test 3` are overlapping each other.

I'm actually stuck on this and would really like to know if this can be done in the `PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE` EventHandler, so I'm looking forward to seeing what you can come up with.

Comment: That should be possible of course but will require a ton of code which is not going to be well maintainable. So I strongly recommend using an intermediate document and then using another reader+writer instance, just as you mentioned. You can use a byte stream if you don't want to pollute disk. If you really want to do it on the fly then I would not do it with layout but rather with generating the desired pages first, then copying them and then reordering the resultant pages with a slight modification of the header. But again, highly unmaintainable code.